# How to get a list of numbers in a for statement

Tags: python, for-loop

I am currently trying to figure how to get numbers organized.

```
def convert(temp_celsius):
    return temp_celsius * 1.8 + 32

def table(b):
    print('C        F')
    for x in b:
        print('{:10}'.format(convert(x)))

table(range(-30, 50, 10))
```

I need a list of numbers that ranges from -30 to 40 in steps of 10. So I have 2 columns. One with Farhenheit and one with Celsius. I currently only have the columns with the converted Farhenheit.

Comment: Er, you've done it, with `range`. What is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: He needs to print both `Celsius` and `Fahrenheit`, that is his question :) Supposingly he just forgot to add another `format()` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really just a matter of formatting *two* numbers instead of one:

```
print('{:10} {:10}'.format(x, convert(x)))
```

Of course, you'll need to fix up the alignments but that's something you can do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With two format statements:

```
for x in b:
    print('{:10} {:10}'.format(x, convert(x)))
```

Certainly, you just forgot to add the other output.